# DB2 iSeries PDO VARCHAR

Tags: php, linux, apache, pdo, db2

I have successfully installed the ODBC iseries driver on a linux box. And I am calling into a DB2 iseries(6). Everything is running smoothly until I try to pull data from a column CDESC VARCHAR(3000). When the characters are below 255 I get no issues, but when it is over 255 the query fails and breaks the app. The data in the table is well over 255, but I just cannot pull it back out. I have tried CAST(CDESC AS TEXT) AS DESC, but this does not work. Any thoughts on the driver settings or changing the column type? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is "255"? Is that a decimal representation of a character of CDESC, or is it the length of CDESC?

Answer (score 0):

`VARCHAR`is a data type for single-byte character set data [SBCS], not double-byte [storesDBCS]. As such, it is impossible that it could store characters over 255.

If you need to support double byte characters, you might look at `NVARCHAR` which handles Unicode character sets.

Perhaps the issue is in translating to your character set.  Remember that DB2 for i stores SBCS data in EBCDIC based character sets, not ASCII related ones.   What CCSID's are you using on your end, and what is the data stored in?